# local folder not populated when create new project

Tags: laravel, homestead

I am attempting to set up Homestead on a Windows 10 machine using VirtualBox and Vagrant so it can live in a virtual machine.

Using Git Bash, here is the sequence of steps thus far -

- connect to Homestead virtual machine using `vagrant ssh`
- run this command to create a new project called Laravel:
  [image]
- look at folders in Homestead directly on VM:
  [image]

So far, so good.

Now here is where things don't seem to be working properly -

- look in storage location on host operating system where Homestead.yaml is configured to park files
  [image]
  [image]
  but there are no files there

Two questions:

1. What needs to be changed so the files appear in the designated location on Z:?
2. Once the change has been made, how will the files appear there when the project has already been created on the VM?

**EDIT:**
I was able to remove the original Laravel project using the comment below from @dparoli.  After `cd code` I executed `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel Laravel` but encountered the error shown below: `[ErrorException] mkdir(): File exists`.  I'm guessing there's left over stuff from the first attempt.  What should be done to clear up the error?
[image]

Comment: You forgot to `cd code` before run `composer create-project`.

Comment: You need to run the create-project command under the "code" folder, which is mounted within your vm.

Comment: OK, I'll give that a try.  So how do I remove the project that was created in the Homestead folder?

Comment: `rm -rf ~/Laravel`